# sysfs block size count

Tags: sysfs

Is the file located under:

```
/sys/block/<xxx>/size
```

Constantly referencing to 512 byte block count, or is there any special cases where the block count changes?

I'm curious because:

```
thinkpad :: /sys/block/sdf % cat queue/physical_block_size                                                                                                                         
4096
thinkpad :: /sys/block/sdf % cat queue/logical_block_size                                                                                                                          
4096
thinkpad :: /sys/block/sdf % cat size                                                                                                                                              
15408640
```

`15408640 * 512 bytes / 1000000000 = ~8GB` -> the size of my device, its correct but the device is a 4K block device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`size` entry](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/block/genhd.c?v=4.4#L986) returns the [`nr_sects` field](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/genhd.h?v=4.4#L79) of the block device structure. Traditionally, in Unix disk size contexts, “sector” or “block” means 512 bytes, regardless of what the manufacturer of the underlying hardware might call a “sector” or “block”. I can't find authoritative documentation, but looking at the Linux source code (e.g. [1](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/block_dev.c?v=4.4#L483)) [2](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/block_dev.c?v=4.4#L1267)) it looks like the `nr_sects` field is indeed expressed in units of 512 bytes.

You can approach it another way: since there is no file reporting the unit, it has to be a constant unit, otherwise applications wouldn't know what the value means. (The `queue` subdirectory is not necessarily present, it depends on the block device.)